# Custom Accuracy/Loss for each Output in Multiple Output Model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to define custom loss and accuracy functions for each output in a two output neural network model using Keras.  Let's call the two outputs: A and B.

My objectives are:

1. Give the accuracy/loss functions for one of the outputs names such that they can be reported on the same graphs in tensorboard as the same corresponding output from older/existing models I have laying around.  So for example, accuracies and losses for output A in this two output network should be viewable in the same graph in tensorboard as output A of some older model that I have.  More specifically, these older models all output `A_output_acc`, `val_A_output_acc`, `A_output_loss` and `val_A_output_loss`.  So I want the corresponding metric readouts for the `A` output in this new model to have those names as well so that they are viewable/comparable on the same graph in tensorboard.
2. Allow for easy configuration of accuracy/loss functions so that I can swap at whim different losses/accuracies for each output without hard coding them.

I have a `Modeler` class that constructs and compiles a network.  The relevant code follows.

```
class Modeler(BaseModeler):
  def __init__(self, loss=None,accuracy=None, ...):
    """
    Returns compiled keras model.  

    """
    self.loss = loss
    self.accuracy = accuracy
    model = self.build()

    ...

    model.compile(
        loss={ # we are explicit here and name the outputs even though in this case it's not necessary
            "A_output": self.A_output_loss(),#loss,
            "B_output": self.B_output_loss()#loss
        },
        optimizer=optimus,
        metrics= { # we need to tie each output to a specific list of metrics
            "A_output": [self.A_output_acc()],
                            # self.A_output_loss()], # redundant since it's already reported via `loss` param,
                                                        # ends up showing up as `A_output_loss_1` since keras
                                                        # already reports `A_output_loss` via loss param
            "B_output": [self.B_output_acc()]
                            # self.B_output_loss()]  # redundant since it's already reported via `loss` param
                                                        # ends up showing up as `B_output_loss_1` since keras
                                                        # already reports `B_output_loss` via loss param
        })

    self._model = model


  def A_output_acc(self):
    """
    Allows us to output custom train/test accuracy/loss metrics to desired names e.g. 'A_output_acc' and
    'val_A_output_acc' respectively so that they may be plotted on same tensorboard graph as the accuracies from
    other models that same outputs.

    :return:    accuracy metric
    """

    acc = None
    if self.accuracy == TypedAccuracies.BINARY:
        def acc(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.accuracy == TypedAccuracies.DICE:
        def acc(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.accuracy == TypedAccuracies.JACARD:
        def acc(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.jacard_coef(y_true, y_pred)
    else:
        logger.debug('ERROR: undefined accuracy specified: {}'.format(self.accuracy))

    return acc


  def A_output_loss(self):
    """
    Allows us to output custom train/test accuracy/loss metrics to desired names e.g. 'A_output_acc' and
    'val_A_output_acc' respectively so that they may be plotted on same tensorboard graph as the accuracies from
    other models that same outputs.

    :return:    loss metric
    """

    loss = None
    if self.loss == TypedLosses.BINARY_CROSSENTROPY:
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.loss == TypedLosses.DICE:
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.loss == TypedLosses.JACARD:
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.jacard_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    else:
        logger.debug('ERROR: undefined loss specified: {}'.format(self.accuracy))

    return loss


  def B_output_acc(self):
    """
    Allows us to output custom train/test accuracy/loss metrics to desired names e.g. 'A_output_acc' and
    'val_A_output_acc' respectively so that they may be plotted on same tensorboard graph as the accuracies from
    other models that same outputs.

    :return:    accuracy metric
    """

    acc = None
    if self.accuracy == TypedAccuracies.BINARY:
        def acc(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.accuracy == TypedAccuracies.DICE:
        def acc(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.accuracy == TypedAccuracies.JACARD:
        def acc(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.jacard_coef(y_true, y_pred)
    else:
        logger.debug('ERROR: undefined accuracy specified: {}'.format(self.accuracy))

    return acc


  def B_output_loss(self):
    """
    Allows us to output custom train/test accuracy/loss metrics to desired names e.g. 'A_output_acc' and
    'val_A_output_acc' respectively so that they may be plotted on same tensorboard graph as the accuracies from
    other models that same outputs.

    :return:    loss metric
    """

    loss = None
    if self.loss == TypedLosses.BINARY_CROSSENTROPY:
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.loss == TypedLosses.DICE:
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    elif self.loss == TypedLosses.JACARD:
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return self.jacard_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    else:
        logger.debug('ERROR: undefined loss specified: {}'.format(self.accuracy))

    return loss


  def load_model(self, model_path=None):
    """
    Returns built model from model_path assuming using the default architecture.

    :param model_path:   str, path to model file
    :return:             defined model with weights loaded
    """

    custom_objects = {'A_output_acc': self.A_output_acc(),
                      'A_output_loss': self.A_output_loss(),
                      'B_output_acc': self.B_output_acc(),
                      'B_output_loss': self.B_output_loss()}
    self.model = load_model(filepath=model_path, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    return self


  def build(self, stuff...):
    """
    Returns model architecture.  Instead of just one task, it performs two: A and B.

    :return:            model
    """

    ...

    A_conv_final = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation="sigmoid", name="A_output")(up_conv_224)

    B_conv_final = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation="sigmoid", name="B_output")(up_conv_224)

    model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[A_conv_final, B_conv_final], name="my_model")
    return model
```

The training works fine.  However, when I go to load the model for inference later, using the above `load_model()` function, Keras complains that it doesn't know about the custom metrics I have given it:

```
ValueError: Unknown loss function:loss
```

What seems to be happening is that Keras is appending the returned function created in each of the custom metric functions above (`def loss(...)`, `def acc(...)`) to the dictionary key given in the `metrics` parameter of the `model.compile()` call.
So, for example the key is `A_output` and we call the custom accuracy function, `A_output_acc()` for it, which returns a function called `acc`.  So the result is `A_output` + `acc` = `A_output_acc`.  This means that I can't name those returned functions: `acc`/`loss` something else, because that will mess up the reporting/graphs. 
This is all fine and well, BUT I don't know how to write my `load` function with a properly defined `custom_objects` parameter (or define/name my custom metrics functions for that matter) so that Keras knows which custom accuracy/loss functions are to be loaded with each output head.

More to the point, it seems to be wanting a `custom_objects` dictionary of the following form in `load_model()` (which won't work for obvious reasons):

```
custom_objects = {'acc': self.A_output_acc(),
                  'loss': self.A_output_loss(),
                  'acc': self.B_output_acc(),
                  'loss': self.B_output_loss()}
```

instead of:

```
custom_objects = {'A_output_acc': self.A_output_acc(),
                  'A_output_loss': self.A_output_loss(),
                  'B_output_acc': self.B_output_acc(),
                  'B_output_loss': self.B_output_loss()}
```

Any insights or work-arounds?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've confirmed the reasoning above about key/function name concatenation IS correct for the `metrics` parameter of Keras' `model.compile()` call. HOWEVER, for the `loss` parameter in `model.compile()`, Keras just concatenates the key with the word `loss`, yet expects the name of the custom loss function in the `custom_objects` parameter of `model.load_model()`...go figure.

Comment: Can you also maybe please check this question out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180206/accuracy-on-a-subsection-of-categories-in-keras

Answer (score 0):

Remove the () at the end of your losses and metrics and that should be it. It'll look like this instead

```
loss={ 
       "A_output": self.A_output_loss,
       "B_output": self.B_output_loss
      }
```